# как на аиограм получить все сообщение с чата где ввели команду и узнать айди всех тех отправихшся сообщений?

Tags: python, aiogram

как на аиограм получить все сообщение с чата где ввели команду и узнать айди всех тех отправихшся сообщений (и если попадается опять айди которые было уже найдено то не получать) ?

Comment: Покажите свои попытки решить эту "задачу"

Comment: chat_members = await bot.get_chat_member(chat_id)
user_ids = [member.user.id for member in chat_members]
await message.answer(user_ids)

Comment: @MajekProMaster для бота существуют только новые сообщения с момента его добавления в чат. Невозможно получить доступ к тем сообщениям что были отправлены ранее‍♀️

Comment: Я понял. Но как тогда работает зазывала бот?

Comment: Использует библиотеку telethon. Подключается от реального аккаунта и чекает id юзеров, id сообщений. В Telegram Bot API нельзя получить список участников группы, только общее количество getChatMemberCount, список администраторов getChatAdministrators и информацию о конкретном участнике чата по заранее известному id пользователя getChatMember.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы получить id чата, где ввели команду используйте `message.chat.id`, для получения id сообщения используйте `message.message_id`.

Вы можете вывести эти самые id через `print()`, например, таким образом:

```python
arr = []
chat_id = message.chat.id

    if chat_id not in arr:
      arr.append(chat_id)
      print(chat_id)
```

Comment: да но я хочу получать еще все сообщения которые были введены пользователями и получать айди авторов сообщений

Comment: Вы не сможете получить все сообщения, которые были отправлены в этом чате. Для этого их нужно логировать и сохранять куда-то, а после обрабатывать, как указано на примере.

Comment: Я понял. Но как тогда работает зазывала бот?